# Convert PDF to Image(s) with different resolution using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have to convert the pdf file (with more text) to images with different resolution.

I am executing the following commands:

**width:1024px**

```
convert -density 150 -antialias -resize 1024x -quality 80 "${inputFilePath}"  "${outputFilePath}"
```

**width:720px**

```
 convert -density 150 -antialias -resize 720x -quality 80 "${inputFilePath}"  "${outputFilePath}"
```

**width:320px**

```
convert -density 150 -antialias -resize 320x -quality 80 "${inputFilePath}"  "${outputFilePath}"
```

The generated images are not clear. 
Can you help me to understand what I have to change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couple of notes that probably will not effect the output  but are wrong in your code. You only need convert or convert.exe; my conversions work with just convert but it may depend on your setup. "${inputFilePath}" should come after -density. Also if you have three different size outputs you can combine them into one command using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your density to get better quality. -antialias will not help in your ImageMagick command. It is only used when adding new text. Put the density after convert and then put the input. Put your quality after the input and before the output. Use parenthesis processing with clones to generate all 3 results in one convert command.

```
convert -density 300 input \
\( -clone 0 -resize 1024x -quality 80 +write output1 \) \
\( -clone 0 -resize 720x -quality 80 +write output2 \) \
\( -clone 0 -resize 320x -quality 80 +write output3 \) \
null:
```